# WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Taking the poison pill

Tags: python, airflow

I have recently upgraded my Airflow cluster from 1.7.1.3 to 1.10.2 with mysql as backend and rabbitmq for message passing. After upgrading i am seeing this issue in some of my tasks -

```
WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Taking the poison pill.
```

This randomly comes once in a while in any task. I have not marked this task success externally but still i am getting this error. Has anyone else faced this? How to fix this ?

Comment: how did u resolve?

Comment: @tooptoop4 As of now i just increased the retries which is a workaround to this. This doesn't seem to be a timeout error as in some of tasks i am getting this error even when it has run only for couple of minutes while some long running tasks like 4-5 hours don't give this error and run successfully.

Comment: I got the same issue as here.

Answer (score 6):

This error typically occurs when a task has timed out. You could increase the timeout in case your task takes a long time to execute.

You could also look into [visibility timeouts](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout) in case you are using Celery with Redis as the backend.

Comment: what is the specific timeout config setting?

Comment: @meghdeep I recently got this error again in a task which gave this error within one minute of getting triggered. Can it because of some other issue other than timeout ?

Comment: It appears from the source code https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e1876250125ecd2d8556a5475a40459469ed29bf/airflow/jobs.py#L2690 that the task instance doesn't have a return code for some reason. That is the reason for this warning. You'll have to look into your code as to why that is happening. Timeouts will cause it but there could be several other causes that can only be understood by looking into the code.

If you are reliant on API calls, they might be failing and causing the program to crash on occasion.

Comment: Hi, am facing similar issue when KubernetesPodOperator which submits a Python code. Could you please let me know how do you identify which piece of code is causing the issue. Though the pod is completing without any issues but am having issues with airflow logs. Logging get stopped when a task is taking more time and write error(Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.) at the last. But there is no issue with the pod and it run fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got same warning (followed by an error). I didn't use mysql as backend and rabbitmq for message passing as you did. I was loading data from 2 different files into 2 different tables in bigquery as two parallel tasks (GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator):

```
    INFO - Subtask ... WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Taking the poison pill.
    INFO - Subtask ... INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 176
    INFO - Subtask ... ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
    ...
    ERROR - (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction') [SQL: 'UPDATE task_instance SET state=%s WHERE task_instance.task_id = %s AND task_instance.dag_id = %s AND task_instance.execution_date = %s'] [parameters: ('queued', 'subdag_name_task_name', 'dag_name.subdag_name', datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 12, 11, 8, 53, 539047, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Like for you the error occurs a few minutes only after having started.

**Solution:** Running the tasks one after another instead of in parallel solved the issue in my case.

There is the url provided at the end of the error for more details about this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had left a database connection open.

The error disappeared after i ran `connection.close()`.  I realize this isn't a very complete answer... at all... but hopefully it will help someone else.